# Add text to an ArrayList in a table formate using Java

Tags: java

I am collecting some data that I want to add to an ArrayList. Once the I am done with adding all of my data in the ArrayList, I output it in a text Area (JavaFX). 
My question is, how can I do something similar to printf

```
System.out.printf( "%5s %10s %15s  %n", " Jan", "Feb", "Mar");

arrayList.add( "%5s %10s %15s  %n", " Jan", "Feb", "Mar");
```

My goal is to store/output some data into/out of the ArrayList in a table formate instead of manually doing it by adding spaces and lines etc.. to make it look like a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.format` to format the string in first place. Then store it in the Array:

```
String out = String.format( "%5s %10s %15s  %n", " Jan", "Feb", "Mar");
arrayList.add(out);
```